# How to import .csv file in existing table in SQL Navigator?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-navigator

Is there a way to import a .csv file into a existing table by using SQL Navigator v7 ?

Comment: Use an Oracle External Table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [import table](http://documents.software.dell.com/doc96637) wizard in sql navigator.

If you have access to DB server, you may use [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)

If you working remotely, [SQL Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) will help.